# How do I get the sticker behind the steel blocks in Gigabyte Grounds Stage 2?

Tags: kirby-planet-robobot

In Stage 2 of Gigabyte Grounds, after the fight with Miasmoros, there is a sticker behind several steel blocks and a single bomb tile. I've tried using Whip to detonate the bomb tile, but it's out of reach.

How do I get the sticker behind the steel blocks?

[image: sticker behind steel blocks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a video tutorial, starting from 8.05:

<sub>(courtesy of [packattack04082](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCg_j7kndWLFZEg4yCqUWPCA))</sub>

Kirby uses [Toxic Smog](https://kirby.fandom.com/wiki/Poison#Techniques) holding <kbd>B</kbd>:

> Kirby exhales a poisonous gas in front of him. It can be **moved by fans and can destroy blocks**.

a *Poison* technique (obtained after inhaling Miasmoros).

Comment: That explains the poison enemy above the steel blocks.

Comment: @Stevoisiak I think that fan too was a hint